# How to display the entire message history in Twilio Flex when an incoming or outgoing sms is sent?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

When I send an incoming or outgoing sms request, a new conversation is created and, accordingly, the message block is empty, but I need previous messages from this number to be loaded there. Maybe it can be done somehow through a plugin?

I'm just stuck right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Conversations, you can use 'parked interactions' so that essentially a conversation is 'paused' rather than ended, and its history is shown when the conversation is resumed.

Here's some docs about it: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/conversations/park-an-interaction

There's a plugin you can use to do this: https://github.com/TwilioLatamEngHub/plugin-conversations-park-an-interaction